# Make queuename in JMSTemplate dynamic based on type of record

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I am using JSMItemWriter in a spring Batch application.
Is it possible to dynamically set the queue name or dynamically define a jmsTemplate at runtime instead of defining it as a bean in the code

Depending on the type of record passed to the JSMItemWriter, i would need to write to a different queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a jms writer for each queue and use a [ClassifierCompositeItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html). This composite writer will classify items dynamically at runtime and call the delegate writer accordingly.